# Не работает подзагрузка

Tags: android, прокрутка

Привет всем!
У меня есть приложение, которое умеет скачивать с сервера данные и красиво выводить их в виде списка.
Мне же нужно научить приложение выводить данные пачками, скажем по 10 элементов листа. После прокрутки экрана - подгружать и выводить очередные 10 и т.д..
Вот написал код, но он не работает - подгружает только лишь "`number`" из них

```
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    MyTask mt = new MyTask();
    Log.d("qwe", "create MyTask: " + mt.hashCode());
    mt.execute();

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int from, int number, int counter) {

            if (view.getAdapter() != null && !((from + number) >= counter)) {
                from = from + number + 1;

                MyTask mt = new MyTask();
                Log.d("qwe", "create MyTask: " + mt.hashCode());
                mt.execute();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask - асинхронная штука. это значит, что вызов **notifyDataSetChanged()** после запуска таска не гарантирует того, что в адаптере listView уже появятся те данные, которые были подгружены.

Напиши в адаптере для listView метод addToData(), в котором ты добавишь в адаптер очередные подгруженные элементы и там вызови метод **notifyDataSetChanged()**

Comment: Может просто notify нужно вызвать вовремя?

Comment: вызывай в методе -   protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)

Comment: Gorets, все-равно облом
Просто загружаются первые number картинок и все..